# How do you implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer to translate and dismiss a UITableViewController with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I am attempting to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to translate and dismiss a UITableViewController. I want the gesture to trigger translation of the TableView *only* when it has reached the bottom of its scroll view and dismiss the TableView when it has been translated 1/3 the height of the screen. I've tried to add the GestureRecognizer when the TableView has reached the bottom of its scroll view, but the application ends up adding the gesture recognizer and disabling the freedom to scroll back up in the TableView.

I can supply code upon request, but I should be able to follow general solutions you may have.

Thanks in advance.

Few extra things to note:

- I've added the gesture recognizer to the table view
- I want to create a similar effect to a particular view in Facebook's iPhone application. In their app, whenever you select a photo from a photo album, it presents a TableView that allows you to translate and dismiss it whenever you reach the any of the edges in its scrollview.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // MARK: - Scrollview dismiss from bottom

    let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    // Detects if scroll view is at bottom of table view

    if scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight {

        println("Reached bottom of table view")

        self.panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "slideViewFromBottom:")
        self.imageTableView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }
}

func slideViewFromBottom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(imageTableView).y
    let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.imageTableView)
    var centerOfImageTableView = self.imageTableView.center.y


    switch recognizer.state {

    case .Began:
        // Touches begin
        println("Touches began")

    case .Changed:

        // Limits view translation to only pan up 
        if velocity.y < 0.0 {
            centerOfImageTableView = self.screenbounds.height/2 + translation
        }

    case .Ended:

        // Determines length of translation to be animated
        let moveToTop = screenbounds.height + translation

        // Animates view depending on view location at end of gesture
        if  translation <= -UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height/2 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
                self.imageTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -moveToTop)
                return
            }
            delay(0.3) {
                self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }
        }

        else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
                self.imageTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -translation)
                return
            }
            recognizer.enabled = false
        }

    default:
        println("Default executed")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please supply the code.